# gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet | Increase the swipe down area of bottom sheet

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

[image]

Hi All,

I am using https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet

I need to increase the swipe-down area of the bottom sheet as highlighted below. Currently, it is only enabled on the handle indicator as I have set the  `enableContentPanningGesture={false}`  so that content inside the sheet is scrollable.

I tried adding the [PanResponder](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) on the highlighted partof the content as below :

```
const ActionSheetHeader = (props) => {
  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true, // detect pan down
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        sheetRef?.current.close();?
      },
    }),
  ).current;
  return (
    <View
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
{/* Contents of header */}
   </View>
)

 <BottomSheetModal
        snapPoints={['100%']}
        name="MySheet"
        onDismiss={onDismiss}
        ref={sheetRef}
        style={styles.container}
        backgroundStyle={styles.backgroundStyle}
        handleIndicatorStyle={styles.handleIndicatorStyle}
        enableContentPanningGesture={false}
        stackBehavior="push">
        <BottomSheetView>
          <ActionSheetHeader />
          <AcionSheetContent /> // contents
        </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheetModal>
```

When I drag over the highlighted section, action sheet closes without any animation, is it possible to have the same behavior as we pull down the sheet from the handle Indicator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can put that highlighted component inside the prop "handleComponent"
that way the whole highlighted section would be considered as the handle and should behave like expected